# Authentication required before suspend

Tags: suspend, policykit

Since the last update of Ubuntu 14.04, when I press the sleep button in my laptop, a pop-up window appears with "Authentication is required for suspending the system".

Password is not requested when closing the lid. However, this doesn't work when another monitor is plugged in.

Is there anything that can be set up (in sudoers or somewhere else) to avoid this password prompt?

Comment: You can find solution here `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466504`

Comment: No, I can't. The question is about how to avoid password before suspending, not after.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Using Polkit

Add yourself to `users` group by

```
sudo usermod -aG users "$USER"
```

You need to **reboot** your computer after the following steps.

#### 1. If PolKit version >= 0.106

You can check version of Polkit by: `pkaction --version`

If PolKit version < 0.106, there are **NO** `.rules` files but only old 
`.pkla` and `.conf` files because those Polkit versions do not have 
the Javascript interpreter.

Just adding a file `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/85-suspend.rules` with:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" &&
        subject.isInGroup("users")) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

And in Terminal, type:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
sudo chmod 644 /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/85-suspend.rules
```

#### 2. If PolKit version < 0.106

In this case, adding a file `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-enable-suspend-on-lockscreen.pkla` with:

```
[Allow suspending in lockscreen]
Identity=unix-group:users
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

In bash, type:

```
sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-enable-suspend-on-lockscreen.pkla
```

[More about pklocalauthority](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html)

## Using Power Manager settings (not sure if it works)

In XFCE Power Manager:

1. Under the `Security` tab:

   - Set `Automatically lock the session` to **Never**
   - Check `Lock the screen when the system is going for sleep`
2. Under the `Display` tab, blank the screen after 15 minutes. Set `Sleep`
   and `Switch off` times to be disabled (greyed out).
3. Under the `System` tab, set system sleep mode to `Suspend` after an half of hour.

---

**References:**

- [stintel's blog](https://stijn.tintel.eu/blog/2015/09/11/polkit-requesting-root-password-to-suspend-after-updating-version-0112-to-0113)
- [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1605189/comments/7)

Comment: In xfce4, the settings change works

Answer (score 23):

1. In command line run:

   ```
   locate -b org.freedesktop.login1.policy
   ```

   The found file is

   ```
   /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy
   ```
2. In the file, near line

   ```xml
   <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend">
   ```

   check these:

   ```xml
   <defaults>
       <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
       <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
       <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
   </defaults>
   ```

<sup>([Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276864))</sup>

Comment: For Ubuntu 15.10 (wily) such solution should work as well.

Comment: It does not ask me for password anymore, but I do not remember doing anything and I have those lines to <allow_any>auth_admin_keep</allow_any> What do they mean? Is there any security concern with changing them to "yes"?

Comment: Here I needed also to change `<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions">`;

Comment: Great answer. I also found a solution to other problems I had... Namely the system inhibitor not allowing the suspend for 15 seconds or so.

Comment: Does any authoritative source really advise this? Files in `/usr/share` should not be edited; that prefix is intended for read-only files installed by packages and not modified by users. The proper way is to copy the file to another, equivalent location like `/etc`, where editing is allowed, then make changes there. It would also be preferable to explain why these changes fix the problem, i.e. what the original problem is - e.g. what the (in my case) previous value of `auth_admin_keep` means, and why it's not right.

Comment: According to [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Configuration), editing the `.policy` files is NOT the correct way.