# Authenticate to suspend?

Tags: permissions, suspend, power-management, authentication

Fresh install of LUbuntu 16.04 on a Compaq CQ58 (El cheapo AMD C60 laptop from Wal*Mart, bought on Black Friday 2012.)

I walk away from it and it's supposed to suspend.

I come back to an authentication screen requesting my password before it's allowed to suspend. There's also a message in the upper corner saying, "Power Manager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Method call timed out."

Requiring authentication to suspend defeats the purpose.

Manually suspending by the taskbar button does not require authentication.

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo pm-suspend` from a terminal?

Comment: It asks for a password as anything that starts with "sudo" and after entering my password, it suspends.

Running it without "sudo" results in an error message stating that this utility may only be run by the root user... There is only one user on this system, me.

Comment: Ok that's normal that it asks for the password to run `pm-suspend`.  Now after you tried to wake up the laptop by pressing a key, did it wake up again normally?

Comment: Yes, It woke up normally back to the desktop with the terminal window open. (Did not go to a login screen.)

Not sure if I need to give it a time limit for it to wake to a login screen, but I don't think it would matter since the system is mostly dormant in suspend.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug.

Please add yourself to [Bug #1605189](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1605189) to have your voice heard (the green writing near the top of the bug's page).

You can find a [workaround in another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543921/authentication-required-before-suspend), but for me, it prevents me from using the computer when waking from suspend :(