# Cannot use hibernate mode lubuntu

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I'm a new user to the linux kernel, I am using lubuntu 21.04
I have setup LXQt to hibernate when I close the lid, but instead of it hibernating it just gives me this error:

Power Manager Error (D-BUS call) org.freedesktop.DBus.Error (I Couldn't see the rest here)
Permission Denied

But in my other user it works perfectly. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I don't know your issue, but this is first obvious thought.  Have you created enough swap for your system to actually hibernate?   By default Lubuntu 21.04 installs and creates a 512MB swap partition, meaning I don't believe any machine it was installed on will be able to hibernate by default (not enough swap for RAM to be written on; `calamares` the installer requires 1GB to run properly so you'll have to increase swap size beyond the default).  Did you increase swap?  https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-21-04-hirsute-and-up/2591

Comment: Maybe also useful; please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/543921/authentication-required-before-suspend  though it could be more of a problem, ie. https://askubuntu.com/questions/543921/authentication-required-before-suspend  (this bug is likely your issue!)  If you believe the bug is you, please hit the "*affects me too* to add heat to the bug & thus attention..  Multiple links can be found in the bug report